# Problem with backup / restore a table with a composite data type column

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have a table

```
europa=# \d europa.recurring_payment
                                                     Table "europa.recurring_payment"
      Column      |                  Type                   | Collation | Nullable |                       Default                        
------------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------------
 id               | bigint                                  |           | not null | nextval('europa.recurring_payment_id_seq'::regclass)
 previous_payment | bigint                                  |           |          | 
 serial           | bigint                                  |           | not null | 
 execution_date   | date                                    |           | not null | 
 information      | europa.recurring_payment_information    |           | not null | 
 responsability   | europa.recurring_payment_responsability |           | not null | 
 status           | europa.recurring_payment_status         |           | not null | 'pending'::europa.recurring_payment_status
Indexes:
    "recurring_payment_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "recurring_payment_previous_payment_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (previous_payment) REFERENCES europa.recurring_payment(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "europa.recurring_payment" CONSTRAINT "recurring_payment_previous_payment_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (previous_payment) REFERENCES europa.recurring_payment(id)

europa=#
```

It works perfect and contains data. The problem is that when I do a backup / restore when restoring that table, it informs me that the information in the information column is not correct (it is a composite data type that I have created).

I do the backup in the following way:

```
pg_dump -U dba --disable-triggers --column-insert europa > europa.sql
```

and the restore (after creating an empty database)

```
psql -U dba europa < europa.sql
```

The errors it presents are like the following one, one for each tuple of the table in question:

```
ERROR:  la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo bigint: «business»
LÍNEA 1: ...VISA CREDITO"",""juan popoloro"",39655721)",,1)', '("(2,euro...
                                                              ^
ERROR:  la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo bigint: «business»
LÍNEA 1: ...BITO PRISMA"",""chrisin wieini"",39080231)",,1)', '("(2,euro...
                                                              ^
ERROR:  la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo bigint: «business»
LÍNEA 1: ... CREDITO"",""Juan Perez Garcia"",25666777)",,5)', '("(2,euro...
                                                              ^
ERROR:  la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo bigint: «business»
LÍNEA 1: ...,""VISA CREDITO"",""leo popolo"",40896935)",,3)', '("(2,euro...
```

Apparently either the pg_dump does not backup well the composite data type or the restore does not interpret well what pg_dump created previously. The same is true using copy instead of column-insert.

Is there a better way to restore / backup this table?

Thank you in advance.-

Comment: What it is saying is `the input syntax is not valid for type bigint: "business"`. I am not seeing a `business` column in the `recurring_payment` table, so I'm assuming it is in the composite type. You will need to provide more information about the composite type and how it was created. Add as update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your dump does not contain a composite data type definition. Open dump file in a text editor or grep it for composite data type definition command.

> after creating an empty database
> The empty database does not contain a composite data type definition of course.